# how to change a partiuclar model data in backbone.js

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js

e.g. I have a model in Backbone.js Content and collection of this model Contents.

the model has attribute

{ id:1 , name:'rahul ',age: 27 }

now if i want to update the model with id=1 in my collection then what will be the code ?
e.g i want to update name from rahul to mehta .

```
 Content = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
  }
});
Contents = Backbone.Collection.extend({  
  model : Content,
  initialize: function(models, args) {
        console.log('in contents'+this.length);
    }
});
```

what will be the code for this .?

How i will get the model from my collection of models ?

```
{id:1,name:mehta ,age : 27 }
```

and then i need to update the content of that ?should i need to change the complete data to the model or part of data only i need to update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question:

```
 var rahul = contents.get(1);
 rahul.set({name: "mehta"});
```

Second question: this within initialize would be the collection.

Last question: you update what you want to update on the model using the set function of the model.

Please read the documentation: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Comment: if my unique field is not id its contentid then ? please update the answer.

Comment: Done it pls chk http://rahulmehta1.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/to-change-particular-model-data-in-collection-in-backbone-js/